# Unreal Engine 4 Cast to parent Class Fails

Tags: casting, unreal-engine4, blueprint

I want to Cast a Child to his Base Class.

I have a Class called Road_Empty and a child Class Road_Left.

Iam using this flow to spawn a Random Road Tile.

[Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZ5yp.png)

This should run smoothly. But the Cast fails evertime.

What is wrong there?

Comment: Is your `Classes` variable type of `TArray<TSubclassOf<class Road_Empty>>` or it's blueprint equivalent?

Comment: Did you check with a breakpoint what the returned value was when the cast failed?

Comment: *Facepalm* thats it, it was the false type

Answer (score 0):

Though you've found that the reason is Classes are filled with wrong types, I'd like to provide some more information:

1. You don't have to cast child classes objects to parent class object, since they can be used directly as parent class object.
2. If your spawning failed so it returns `None`, the cast can also failed. The most common failure is because of collision handling, but in your case of `Always Spawn, Ignore Collisions` then it can hardly fails.